# EL in <sec:authorize> access attribute

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Is it not possible to use EL in  access attribute? I dislike to hardcode the role names in the tag, instead would like to use a constant. But it is throwing an exception saying:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: abc.jsp(19,4) According to TLD or
attribute direc tive in tag file, attribute access does not accept
any expressions

Here is what I have in jsp(using unstandard taglib for constants):

<%@taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/unstandard-1.0" prefix="un"%>
<un:useConstants className="com.xxx.PrivilegeConstants" var="privilege" />
.....

<sec:authorize access="hasRole('${privilege.USER_ROLE}')">  // throwing ex here
   security content here....
</sec:authorize>    

Is there any other alternative? Thanks in advance...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the support was added later on. See the JIRA [here](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1611). Using the version which adds this support should work, I guess.

Comment: Thanks a lot, looks like it was fixed in 3.1 but I am using Spring Security 3.0.5. Interestingly there is another JIRA [here](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1456) that is similar but it was mentioned as fixed in 3.0.3 not sure it does n't work in 3.0.5!!

Comment: For now I fixed it using ugly of scriplets :(    <%@page import="com.xxx.PrivilegeConstants"%>    
    <sec:authorize access="hasRole('<%=PrivilegeConstants.USER_ROLE%>')">
             ... show content here....
    </sec:authorize>